# How can I feed the output of DynamoDB's Item.getNumberSet() into Item.withNumberSet()?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have an [`Item`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.html#withNumberSet-java.lang.String-java.util.Set-) that contains a Number Set (NS) attribute. The [`getNumberSet(String attrName)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.html#getNumberSet-java.lang.String-) will return a `Set<BigDecimal>`.

My intention is to take that NumberSet and store it in another `Item` but the [`withNumberSet(String attrName, Set<Number> vals)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.html#withNumberSet-java.lang.String-java.util.Set-) will not accept a `Set<BigDecimal>` as input although [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is a `Number`

```
AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDbClient = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
DynamoDB db = new DynamoDB(dynamoDbClient);

Table table = db.getTable("test-table");
GetItemSpec getItemSpec = new GetItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("id", "myid");
Item item = table.getItem(getItemSpec);

Set<BigDecimal> vals = item.getNumberSet("vals");

Item mynewItem =  new Item()
    .withPrimaryKey("id", "id2")
    .withNumberSet("vals", vals); // won't compile
```

This give a `incompatible types: java.util.HashSet<java.math.BigDecimal> cannot be converted to java.util.Set<java.lang.Number>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to create a new `Set<Number>` from the the `Set<BigDecimal>` with:

```
Set<Number> vals = new HashSet<Number>(item.getNumberSet("vals")); // conversion


Item mynewItem =  new Item()
    .withPrimaryKey("id", "id2")
     .withNumberSet("vals", vals); // won't compile
```